# How to filter NSTableView with predicate

Tags: core-data, filter, nstableview, predicate

How can i filter the records displayed in NSTableView with predicate?
In my entity there is a BOOL isTemp and i want in the table to be displayed only elements which are BOOL = YES.

Comment: What have you tried? Showing some code will encourage people to help you with an answer.

Comment: There is no need of code.I have a NSTablewView and core data Entity.My question is how to filter the content displayed inside.I know how to do that when i use NSSearchField but i don't know how to do it without it.

Comment: "There is no need of code". We don't know if you're setting this up programmatically or not. We don't even know that you're using an `NSArrayController`, since you don't specifically mention that. You'll get (better) answers if you're more precise about what you have set up how, and what you've already tried.

Comment: I solved the problem.Selectin ArrayController in XCode there is a field predicate :)

Comment: Great! You should post your resolution as an answer to your question, for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.Selectin ArrayController in XCode there is a field predicate :)